# Predicting atomic dipole transition properties (reference request?)

Tags: atomic-physics, computational-physics

I am interested in the question of how to predict the strengths of atomic transitions. A quantum 101 approach to solving this problem involves calculating an integral like

$$
\int R_{nl}(r)R_{n'l'}(r) r^3 dr
$$

However, in experimental atomic physics, we pretty much never calculate transition dipole elements this way*. Instead, we infer the transition dipole elements from excited state lifetimes. I understand that this is because the simple integral above is insufficiently accurate for multi-electron atoms.

I have code that calculates transition dipole elements this way. When I run it on the Hydrogen 1S <-> 2P transition I get an answer that is within 1% of the experimentally observed value. However, if I run it on the Rb 1S <-> 2P transition I am off by over a factor of 5. If I run the code on higher hydrogen transitions (e.g. 2P <-> 3S or 3D or something) I again see discrepancies of a few percent or 10 of percent. I would like to learn more about the physics of multi-electron atoms so that I can make more accurate predictions of transition dipole elements, even for multi-electron atoms.

My questions are:

- What is a good reference to learn about multi-electron atoms? I prefer modern references since I find them much easier to read than canonical stuff from e.g. the 40s (even though I know those old books probably have all the answers).
- Short of a reference, could someone who knows about this stuff just post an ordered list of the leading order effects that need to be taken into account to get the correct answers? E.g., for my Rubidium calculation I think I am so far off because I'm not taking into account penetration of the single valence electron into the closed inner shell. This penetration leads to an increased [effective nuclear charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge#) (beyond unity which is what it would be if the electron stayed totally outside the closed shell). But what are the other effects and, quantitatively, how large is their impact on this calculation?

*[Here is an online textbook](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Introductory_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fitzpatrick)/12%3A_Time-) which does show a calculation in this vein, but it does hide the messy integration behind the phrase "Some straightforward, but tedious, integrations reveals that..."

Comment: *I get the correct answer to with [sic] 40%.* A 40% error sounds very bad; so much so that one could very easily argue that you *didn't* get a correct answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos well sure, but that was better than being off by a factor of 5 leaving an effective nuclear charge of unity. I'm seeking references to help see if the discrepancy I see is due to an error I've made with the simple theory, or if I need to include a more detailed physical model, and, if so, **specifically** what effects need to be included in the more sophisticated model.

Comment: Whether it's a factor of 5 or a factor of 1.4, you're still far off from calling either result "correct". You should be looking for references that describe how to do what you want, rather than asking for "what you're missing" (largely because that it seems to me that what you're missing is probably everything, given how far off 40% is from the true result).

Comment: @KyleKanos In the question I literally ask for a reference. For a crude model I'm happy with 40% agreement. I should try my calculations against Hydrogen where I'd expect more accuracy. You seem to be critical of my 40% discrepancy whereas (1) I'm personally proud of getting the right order of magnitude (that means I'm not missing "everything") and (2) am literally asking in this questions for references or specific ideas for how I can quantitatively improve my theoretical prediction. Are you just nit picking my phrasing?

Comment: @KyleKanos when I run my code on the Hydrogen S<->P transition (as opposed to Rb) I get better than 1% agreement. So the question can be rewritten asking about what effects need to be taken into account to predict transition dipole elements in multi-electron atoms.

Comment: @KyleKanos I've reworked the entire question in light of my last comment. I think it's much more clear now.

Comment: Try to look into the book by Zenonas Rudzikas, *Theoretical Atomic Spectroscopy*, Cambridge 2007, it goes into mathematical details of how the atomic spectra can be calculated, maybe it will be helpful. https://www.cambridge.org/cz/universitypress/subjects/physics/atomic-physics-molecular-physics-and-chemical-physics/theoretical-atomic-spectroscopy?format=PB

Comment: @JánLalinský that reference seems really nice, a lot of information. Will be challenging  work through. I would definitely upvote if that comment was turned to an answer. Possibly mark as answered.